# Order of variables in python using the .update method of sets

Tags: python, set

How are the order of variables decided when updating a set?

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

A.add(8)
print(A)

A.update({-1, -2, -3})
print(A)
```

Why is the order `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, -2, -3, -1}` and not `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, -1, -2, -3}`?

Comment: That's not a list; that's a set. Sets are unordered. You want `[]` for a list.

Comment: Also those aren't variables, they're literals (representations of `int` objects)

Answer (score 3):

When using `{1, 2, 3}` you generate a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which is an unordered object.
You can't expect the set to conserve the order, because it uses a hashtable to avoid double entries of the same value. This is faster than using a list for this case.

When the order matters to you, than you have to use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), on which you can call `.append(element)` or `.insert(position, element)`.

Answer (score 0):

order of elements in a set is undefined.unlike array so you couldn't reference to variable as A[0]=1
moreover, the set elements are usually not stored in order of appearance in the set; this allows checking if an element belongs to a set faster than just going through all the elements of the set.
you can check link below 
https://snakify.org/en/lessons/sets/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. You're on the right track but off on some details. In Python, [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) != [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). ~~The reason that set elements aren't shown in order is that they're listed [based on their hash value](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/360889/352138).~~ **Edit** Actually after doing a bit of research, you're correct about the ordering.